Optimizing Rust struct for LEN == 0 using type system instead of conditionals
I have few different sparse structs that I'm trying to performance optimize a bit.
I'd like to completely remove the conditional (if LEN==0). I could likely do this with a custom macro (ie, define each LEN needed up to 32) but was hoping the type system has a way to handle this and I'm just not finding it (instead, I'd love to be able to use BITMASK.count_ones() in place of LEN but the compiler really doesn't like that idea).
Is there a way to leverage Rust's type system to optimize for the case where LEN==0 vs LEN!=0 without using conditionals?
Stripped down version of my code with comments explaining what I was trying to accomplish:
use std::ops::Mul;

trait MyWrapped<T> {
    fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> T;
}

pub struct MyWrapper<T, const LEN: usize, const BITMASK: usize> {
    data: [T; LEN],
}

impl<T, const LEN: usize, const BITMASK: usize> MyWrapped<T> for MyWrapper<T, LEN, BITMASK>
where
    T: Copy + Default + From<bool> + Mul<T, Output = T>,
{
    fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> T {
        if LEN == 0 {
            Default::default()
        } else {
            let bit: usize = 1 << idx;
            let is_hot = T::from((bit & BITMASK) != 0);
            let i = ((bit - 1) & BITMASK).count_ones() as usize;
            is_hot * self.data[i]
        }
    }
}

// What I'd like to implement:
// impl<T, const BITMASK: usize> MyWrapped<T> for MyWrapper<T, 0, BITMASK> {
//     fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> T {
//         Default::default()
//     }
// }

// impl<T, const LEN: usize, const BITMASK: usize> MyWrapped<T> for MyWrapper<T, LEN, BITMASK>
// where
//     T: Copy + Default + From<bool> + Mul<T, Output = T>,
//     LEN: NonZero, // was hoping that's what this was for but it's not even a trait :/
//                   // tried a few variations of where clauses but didn't get anywhere
// {
//     fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> T {
//         let bit: usize = 1 << idx;
//         let is_hot = T::from((bit & BITMASK) != 0);
//         let i = ((bit - 1) & BITMASK).count_ones() as usize;
//         // can't "cheat" and ignore data if LEN == 0 because OOB
//         is_hot * self.data[i]
//     }
// }

type WrapZero = MyWrapper<i32, 0, 0>;
type WrapOne = MyWrapper<i32, 1, 0b0100>;
type WrapTwo = MyWrapper<i32, 2, 0b0101>;

fn main() {
    let w0 = WrapZero { data: [] };
    let w1 = WrapOne { data: [1] };
    let w2 = WrapTwo { data: [1, 2] };
    println!("Hello, world! {} {} {}", w0.get(2), w1.get(2), w2.get(2));
}

playground link
Still pretty new to Rust so any advice will be appreciated!

These branches are compile-time constants so I'd have to image they're optimized away.

@BallpointBen Hmm, good point. Messing around in playground, it seems like it may be optimized away already in the MIR (but I'm not ready for a proper dive into lower levels just yet). Thanks!
